# How to assemble bike chain with no Master link?

Tags: chain, master-link

I just bought a KMC chain on Amazon, and to my surprise, it didn't come with any kind of master link or connecting pin. I thought this was standard. So, did I just forget to order the part, or can you assemble a chain without using a master link? Both end of the chain terminate in a "small" link.

I haven't seen any specific instructions on how to assemble a chain without a Master link. If your Google-fu is superior to mine, please post a link!

Note this is a 1/8" chain.

Comment: I used the search on this site "[chain tool](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=chain+tool)" to find [do I really need a magic link](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/28773/do-i-really-need-a-magic-link-or-can-i-just-replace-the-pin-on-my-chain) is most of the answer, and [chain attaching](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/question-about-chain-re-attaching) actually has instructions. Those were in the top three or four results for my search. I'm not sure whether some search tips is the answer you wanted, so I'm leaving it as a comment.

Comment: You can buy quick links pretty cheaply as well.

Comment: Believe it or not, magic or master links are a very recent thing, so welcome to a hundred years of cycling tradition!

Comment: If you don't have a chain rivetting tool, now is a good time to buy one so you can shorten the chain. It's worth trying to push the pin back in if only to see if you can do it. But like Batman I'd be inclined to buy a quick link for it, they're cheap and they make life easier.

Comment: Verify the packaging to see if it is supposed to include the missing link.  The KMC chains I have bought came with a missing link.  And you should use missing link.

Comment: You'll need a chain tool to adjust the chain length anyway. As for KMC chains, if you got older stock or a rebranded KMC chain, they sometimes don't come with the missing links.

Comment: Thanks for all the info guys. I will see how many "spare" links I have so I can experiment. But I'll also head over to my LBS and see if I can pick up a quick link for a cheap price. Plus I'll check out my older chains... oh, maybe not. They're probably all 3/32 and this is a 1/8...

Comment: KMC does make quick links for 1/8" chains, but obviously 3/32" chains and links are not interchangable with 1/8" chains (and you obviously should have sprocket designed for 1/8" as well). I don't know if they ship their 1/8" chains with quick links, like the derailleur chains.

Comment: That it is 1/8" makes a difference. I use these chains too and have never had one come with a master link. If you buy a chain tool (you should), make sure it is compatible with 1/8" chains.

Comment: Don’t use a normal rivet for closing unless you have a Rohloff Revolver which is capable of true riveting (and not just pushing the rivet through the chain).

Comment: @PeteH Although not widely used (i.e. shipped on new bikes) till more recently, they are hardly "very recent" ... I can find records of Master links dating back to early 2000's, and am fairly certain I was using them in late 1990's,

Comment: As I understand it this is the norm again. For the thinner chains, few companies offer Master Link style chain links. Usually they ship with a special extra long pin that you can install and then break off the excess.

Comment: @Michael - It isn't ideal, but people have been pushing regular rivets back into the chain for a long time. This is more of a problem on smaller chains than on big chains like a 1/8" chain.

Comment: Interestingly, Shimano don't make a master link for their chains.  They use push-through pins where the end is designed to snap off after installation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a simple chain breaking/Rivet tool to break the chain at one point (while still keeping the pin in the link) and then put the chain on and use the tool again to push the pin in and join the chain like that. That's the way I always do it. Here's a couple of tools that you could try:

- TRIXES Rivet Tool (Very Low Cost): http://amzn.to/1X9NWXI
- Topeak Super Chain Tool (Branded Tool): http://amzn.to/1MDggwF

Best of Luck,
Robert

Comment: Robert is right but if you're going to buy something to shove a pin in, I'd just buy a speed link or 10 and be done with it

Comment: To enter the pin back (yet if it's in the out hole) use a side pull pliers (http://www.hyperclaw.com/water_pump.shtml). It inserts very fine.

Comment: I have successfully used a chain tool to get a pin back in after it has been removed from the chain. It's not easy, but yoyo can do it.

Comment: I have found it hard at the start as well Kibbee, but it gets easier with experience. After doing it a number of times in the past 2 years. I find it to be a quick and painless task now and I find using a **BEND PAPER CLIP** to hold the links together helps. Joining the links like this provides a solid and smooth chain that will not give up that easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be messing with 1/8" chains get a chain tool and forget those master links.

Add *chain tool* or *chain breaker* to your repertoire and power up your google fu.